# Nearby Connections API and WiFi Hotspot

Tags: android, google-nearby

Our app uses Google Nearby Connections API and we have a problem when there is no WiFi router available. When a device creates a WiFi hotspot others can connect to it, but that device itself is not a part of that network.

Is there any workaround for this, or any other suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The host of a WiFi hotspot cannot advertise itself to clients of the network via Nearby Connections, since Nearby Connections uses multicast (mDNS) to communicate amongst *clients* of a multicast-enabled network.

Answer (score 1):

[https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/v11-update](http://API%20Version%2011%20update)

Devices no longer need to be connected to the same multicast-enabled wifi network to discover or connect to each other.